# How to summarize table based on other column values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

There is a `decision` table as follows:

```
Id                decision                  
1                   NULL
1                   NULL
1                   yes
1                   NULL
2                   no
2                   no
2                   no
3                   yes
3                   no
3                   yes
```

The result should return :

```
Id                decision                  
1                   Decision Pending
2                   no
3                   yes
```

So for each Id in the `decision` table:

- If any of the decision value is NULL then it is to be set to
  "decision pending". eg. id 1
- If there is no NULL and any of the decision is yes then final
  decision is set to be "yes". eg. id 3
- If there is no NULL and all the decisions are no then final decision
  is set to be as "no". eg. id 2

What should the azure sql query to get the above mentioned result?

P.S. I am new to SQL, so having trouble figuring this out.

Comment: count(decision) counts non-null values only. count(*) counts rows, including null values.

Comment: Hint: Use case expressions.

Comment: Yes and no are strings? I'd recommend instead using numerical values for, e. g. 0 for 'pending', 1 for 'yes' and 2 for 'no' – then you could just select the minimum of those decisions: `SELECT id, MIN(decision) FROM decision GROUP BY id`.

Comment: Are you doing a SQL course and learning about `some` (or `any`), and `all`? I ask because this would (academically) be a possible use case for those, but in practise I have never used them, and wouldn't really use them here either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  id,
  CASE
    WHEN COUNT(*) > COUNT(decision)
      THEN 'pending'
      ELSE MAX(decision)
  END
    AS decision
FROM
  decision
GROUP BY
  id
```

`GROUP BY id` ensures that you get one row per `id`.

`COUNT(*)` tells you how many rows there are for that `id`.

`COUNT(decision)` tell you how many of those rows have `NOT NULL` decisions.

`COUNT(*) > COUNT(decision)` is therfore `TRUE` if any of the decisions in the group are `NULL`.

`MAX(decision)` returns `yes` if there are any `yes` values in the group, and `no` only if there aren't any `yes` values in the group.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to compare the `count(*)` and `count(decision)` which reveals if a row is null and use an *inline if* to succinctly know to use the aggregate

```
select id, Iif(Count(*)=Count(decision),Max(decision),'Decision Pending')
from Decision
group by id
```